# How can the classic training rule for a ReLU (linear rectifier unit) possibly work?

Tags: neural-network, conv-neural-network

I'm trying to understand how an ordinary linear rectifier unit (not a leaky one, etc) could ever be trained.  Since its derivative is 0 when the weighted sum of inputs is < 0, then its training rule would say that if the weighted sum of inputs is < 0, then the change in weight (for any weight) is 0.  So, how could it ever learn to output a positive value for a particular input, if it doesn't output a positive value for that input to begin with?

Intuitively, if the output is 0 and the target is, say, 1, then you would want to increase the weight of non-zero inputs.  But I don't see how that can be justified in terms of the gradient.

Comment: By using a bias input signal that is initially `> 0`.

Answer (score 1):

Basically - this problem is overcomed by:

1. **Good initialization:** using the so called *He initialization* you make your network units less likely in a region in which they are turned off instantly.
2. **Turned off unit detection:** it's easy to detect units which are constantly outputting 0. You may change the weights of such units when the number of them is to big.
3. **Increase in number of units:** one easy solution for this is to increase number of units in your network. Then the probability that most of units will be turned off decreases. Moreover - this is truly why `relu` was invented. The computations of `relu` value and gradient are much faster then classic activation functions - what makes possible to increase the size of your network.